# React props not working inside <img> tag, but works outside

Tags: reactjs, react-props, faker

This is my `index.js` React App

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';

const App = () => {
    const avatarx = faker.image.avatar();
    return ( 
        <img alt="avatar" src='{avatarx}' />
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

It shows a warning that says `'avatarx' is assigned a value but never used`.

If i use the prop `{avatarx}` outside of the `<img>` tag, then it shows the url of the image(so its working).

But it doesn't work inside the `<img>` tag?

Comment: Remove the single quotes ( ' ) from the src attribute

 src={avatarx}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the braces:

```
<img alt="avatar" src={avatarx} />
```

---

When using attributes in JSX elements, there are a couple options:

```
<Example
  truthyAttribute
  stringAttribute="foo"
  otherAttribute={[1, 2, 3]}
/>
```

The `truthyAttribute` without an explicit value will be set to true on the element.

The `stringAttribute` does not need braces and will be set to its string value on the element.

All other types of values (numbers, arrays, object and all variables) must be wrapped in braces. It is *also* valid to wrap string values in braces!

In your case, you did it the wrong way around so your src attribute was the literal string `{avatarx}` instead of the content of the variable. The warning  you saw was fully justified.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line to

```
<img alt="avatar" src='{avatarx}' />  // you're treating avatarx as a string
```

to this line

```
<img alt="avatar" src={avatarx} /> // remove the single quotes from src attribute
```